# Using a state space model to invert a moving average

Tags: r, state-space-models, moving-average, dlm

Here is the problem :-

We have an AR(1) process, $x[t]$,

ie,

$(x[t] - \mu) = \phi(x[t-1]-\mu) + \epsilon_x[t] $

where $Var(\epsilon_x[t]) = \sigma_x^2$ and $Mean(\epsilon_x[t])=0$

ie. $x[t] = (\mu - \phi * \mu) + \phi x[t-1] + \epsilon_x[t] $

ie. $x[t] = \mu(1 - \phi) + \phi x[t-1] + \epsilon_x[t] $

For convenience I call $\mu(1-\phi)$ as $c$.

ie. $x[t] = c + \phi x[t-1] + \epsilon_x[t] $

We observe the 4 period moving average $y[t]$  of $x[t]$ with noise,

ie.

$ y[t] = 1/4*( x[t] + x[t-1] + x[t-2] + x[t-3] ) + \epsilon_y[t]$

where $Var(\epsilon_y[t]) = \sigma_y^2$ and $Mean(\epsilon_y[t])=0$

***The problem*** is to go from $y[t]$ to $x[t]$.

**Here is my attempt.**

I create the state space formulation of this problem.

The measurement equation being :-

$y[t] = .25 x[t] + .25 x[t-1] + .25 x[t-2] + .25 x[t-3] + \epsilon_y[t]$

The state vector here is $ \begin{bmatrix} x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} $

The state equation is :-

$ 
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} \phi && 0 && 0 && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\ 0 && \phi && 0 && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\
0 && 0 && \phi && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\  0 && 0 && 0 && \phi && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\ 
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ x[t-4] \\ 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\epsilon_x[t] \\ \epsilon_x[t-1] \\ \epsilon_x[t-2] \\ \epsilon_x[t-3] \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} $

The variance-covariance matrix of the error matrix above is :-

$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_x^2 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && \sigma_x^2 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && \sigma_x^2 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && \sigma_x^2 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$

In the language of dlm, I have computed GG and W.

$ GG = \begin{bmatrix} \phi && 0 && 0 && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\ 0 && \phi && 0 && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\
0 && 0 && \phi && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\  0 && 0 && 0 && \phi && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\ 
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix} $

$ W = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_x^2 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && \sigma_x^2 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && \sigma_x^2 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && \sigma_x^2 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Next I write the measurement equation in terms of the state vector at time t.

$ y[t] = 1/4*( x[t] + x[t-1] + x[t-2] + x[t-3] ) + \epsilon_y[t]$

ie.

$ y[t] = 1/4 * x[t] + 1/4 * x[t-1] + 1/4 * x[t-2] + 1/4 * x[t-3]  + 0 * 1 +  \epsilon_y[t]$

ie.

$y[t] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
.25 && .25 && .25 && .25 && 0 
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
+ \epsilon_y[t]
$

In terms of dlm,

the $FF$ matrix is
$ = 
\begin{bmatrix}
.25 && .25 && .25 && .25 && 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$

and $V$ is
$\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_y^2
\end{bmatrix}
$

***Here is the R program which implements the above***

```
library(dlm)
library(zoo)

# Simulating the data.

set.seed(123)
x <- as.zoo( 6 + arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.3)), n=1000, sd=2))
y <- zoo::rollapply(x, width=4, FUN=mean, align="right") + rnorm(1000-3, sd=1)
    
# Set parameter restrictions
# parm[1] = Phi, the AR1 parameter of the x series.I have constrained this to be between -1 and 1.
# parm[2] = the error variance in the x series. I have constrained this to be positive.
# parm[3] = the error variance in the y series. I have constrained this to be positive.
# parm[4] = mu is the mean of the x series. I have constrained this to be positive. I know from the physical interpretation of the problem that
# this is positive. In theory this could be negative. It's not a big deal.
# The intercept of the x series is mu*(1-Phi).

parm_rest <- function(parm){
    return(
        c(1-2*exp(parm[1])/(1+exp(parm[1])),
          exp(parm[2]),
          exp(parm[3]),
          exp(parm[4]))
    )
}

# We setup the state space model.

ssm1 <- function(parm){
    
    parm <- parm_rest(parm)

    GG1  = diag(rep(parm[1],4))
    GG1  = cbind(GG1,rep((1-parm[1])*parm[4],4))
    GG1  = rbind(GG1,c(rep(0,4),1))
    W1 = diag(c(rep(parm[2],4),0))
    return(
        dlm(
            FF = matrix(c(rep(.25,4),0),nr=1),
            V = parm[3],
            GG = GG1,
            W = W1,
            m0 = matrix(c(rep(0,4),1),nr=5),
            # I set the first 4 state variables = x[t]=...=x[t-3]=0
            # the 5th state variable = 1
            # C0 = diag(c(rep(solve(1-parm[1]^2)*parm[2],4),0))
            # parm[1] is between -1 and 1 and can be zero. That is why I did NOT do the above as it may lead to division by 0.
            C0 = diag(c(rep(1000,4),0))
            # There is some uncertainty in the x[0],...,x[3].
            # There is NO uncertainty in the last state variable as it is always = 1 
        )
    )
}

# estimate parameters
fit1 <- dlmMLE(y,parm=c(1,1,1,1),build=ssm1,hessian=T)

# get estimates

coef <- parm_rest(fit1$par)

# get standard errors using delta method
dg1 <- -2 * exp(fit1$par[1])/(1+exp(fit1$par[1]))^2
dg2 <- exp(fit1$par[2])
dg3 <- exp(fit1$par[3])
dg4 <- exp(fit1$par[4])
dg <- diag(c(dg1,dg2,dg3,dg4))
var <- dg%*%solve(fit1$hessian)%*%dg

# print results

coef; sqrt(diag(var))

coef + (2 *  sqrt(diag(var)))
coef - (2 *  sqrt(diag(var)))
```

***Here is the output***

```
> coef; sqrt(diag(var))
[1] 0.6532458 4.4895771 0.6795316 6.0745278
[1] 0.04242776 0.66841183 0.12774506 0.10030250
> 
> coef + (2 *  sqrt(diag(var)))
[1] 0.7381013 5.8264007 0.9350217 6.2751328
> coef - (2 *  sqrt(diag(var)))
[1] 0.5683903 3.1527534 0.4240415 5.8739228
>
```

The first parameter .3 is NOT between [.56,.73]

The error variance in x = 4 is between [3.15,5.82 ]

The error variance in y = 1 is not between [.42,.93 ]

The mean of x = 6 IS between [5.8,6.2]

This behavior is repeated on repeated sampling. In particular the $\phi$ is not covered in the 2 standard deviations of the coef[1].

Can some tell me where I am mistaken ? Theory or programming? I could have made a mistake but I do not see where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The state equation is incorrect. You say:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} \phi && 0 && 0 && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\ 0 && \phi && 0 && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\
0 && 0 && \phi && 0 && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\  0 && 0 && 0 && \phi && c = \mu * (1-\phi) \\ 
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ x[t-4] \\ 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\epsilon_x[t] \\ \epsilon_x[t-1] \\ \epsilon_x[t-2] \\ \epsilon_x[t-3] \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

If we call the last term term $\varepsilon_t$, your model doesn't *know* that the first entry of $\varepsilon_t$ should be exactly equal to the 2nd entry of $\varepsilon_{t+1}$, for example. It assumes the $\varepsilon_t$ are independent across time and so will not respect all those implicit dependencies.

The usual way to cast an $\text{AR}(p)$ model in state space form is the "companion form", which in this case would look like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} \phi && 0 && 0 && 0 && c  \\ 
1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ x[t-4] \\ 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\epsilon_x[t] \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

The first row is then your $\text{AR}(1)$ model and the other rows do the work of "carrying" forward previous values that you need to appear in the observation equation.

As pointed out by @Yves, a better way to handle the constant is then:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ \mu[t]
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} \phi && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1  \\ 
1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ x[t-4] \\ \mu[t-1] \\ 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\epsilon_x[t] \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Good.  I would use $\mu$ as the fourth state component with the transition $\mu[t]= \mu[t-1]$ and a fourth element set to 1 in the observation matrix. The initial variance for $\mu[t]$ should be large or diffuse. Then $\mu$ will no longer be an hyper-parameter (as are $\phi$ and the variances) and the estimate of $\mu$ would simply be the filtered $\widehat{\mu}[T|T]$ where $T$ is the last time, provided that the ML estimation of the hyperparameters have converged.

Comment: Assuming the the observation remains with a zero fourth element I think that the fourth component of the answer is $c[t]$ rather than $\mu[t]$. An equivalent change is to drop the one in the first line of the transition and use a one in the observation matrix (4th position). The first 3 state elements should then fluctuate around zero.

Comment: Dear Yves and Chris, do you mean to use $ c = \mu ( 1- \phi ) $ as the coefficient corresponding to the fifth component which is 1 ? If I do that the standard error in c and phi will be known ( it will be spit out by the program ) , but how will you compute the standard error in $ \mu $ ? That is why I explicitly modelled $ \mu, \phi $ in place of $c$. What do you think about this ?

Comment: Sorry typo in my comments: "fourth" is to be read as "fifth".  If $\mu$ is known to be zero then the state would be 4-dimensional with a transition in "companion form" as in @Chris Haug answer. If a constant $\mu$ is to be added to $x[t]$ hence to $y[t]$  we can make a "state augmentation" using $\mu$ as a new state element. The filltered $\widehat{\mu}(t | t)$ will converge to the estimate of $\mu$ (for given hyper parameters). The standard error can be derived from the filtered variance at $T$. You could use $c$ in the state to shift $x[t]$ as in the answer. This is profile-likelihood.

Comment: Hi again, I have a small query. We could model $\mu$ as hyper parameter as in the original query OR we could make $\mu[t]$ the last element of the state vector as suggested by Yves. My query is : why is modelling $\mu[t]$ as a state variable a better idea? In *both* cases I would get the mean and the standard error of $\mu$. Why is the latter approach preferable?