# State space model to invert moving average of AR1 process whose mean temporarily jumps up once

Tags: r, state-space-models, moving-average, dlm

This is a follow up query of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524937/using-a-state-space-model-to-invert-a-moving-average/524943#524943).

**Here is the problem statement:**

I have an AR1 process say x[t] whose mean jumps up in a given time period.

ie. $x[t]-\mu[t] = \phi (x[t-1] -\mu[t-1]) + \epsilon_x[t]$

For the sake of an example, let's say t=1,...,100.

Then

$\mu[t] = \mu_0$  in the period t=1,...,60 and t=81,...,100.

and

$\mu[t] = \mu_0 + \mu_1$  in the period t=61,...,80.

Further, y[t] is the 4 period (trailing) moving  average of x[t] which is measured with noise.

ie. $ y[t] = 1/4 *(x[t] + x[t-1] + x[t-2] + x[t-3]) + \epsilon_y[t] $

**The problem is to go from the observed** y[t] **to** x[t] **and recover** $\phi,\mu_0,\mu_1,Var(\epsilon_x), Var(\epsilon_y)$

I can formulate this as a **time varying dynamic linear model** in 2 ways.

**Attempt 1:**

I model this problem as:-

$x[t]=\mu_0 (1 -\phi) +  \phi x[t-1] + \epsilon_x[t]$ for $t$ in $\in$ [1,60],[81,100]

and

$x[t]=( \mu_0 + \mu_1 )(1 -\phi) +  \phi x[t-1] + \epsilon_x[t]$ for $t$ in $\in$ [61,80]

Note :
$x[t]-\mu[t] = \phi (x[t-1] -\mu[t-1]) + \epsilon_x[t]$ is true for all points except t = 61, 81. **That is why I think this approach is wrong. Am I right in thinking so?**

Lets examine the model at t=61/81.

At t=61, we have:-

$x[61] - \mu_0 - \mu_1 = \phi( x[60] - \mu_0 - \mu_1) + \epsilon_x[t]$

The $\mu_1$ term should not be there in the right hand side above. That is why it is incorrect.

At t=81, we have:-

$x[81] - \mu_0  = \phi( x[80] - \mu_0) + \epsilon_x[t]$

The $\mu_1$ is missing on the right hand side. That is why this is incorrect.

**I have still programmed this solution.**

In the language of the package dlm in R, we have to, pen down FF,GG,V and W.

The state vector is :

$ 
\begin{bmatrix} x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ \mu_0 \\ \mu_1
\end{bmatrix} 
$

The state evolution matrix is  :

$ GG = 
\begin{bmatrix} \phi && 0 && 0 && 0 && (1-\phi) && (1-\phi) I_t \\
1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
$

where $ I_t $ = 1 in [61,80] and 0 outside. That is why I need a time varying dlm. The GG is different inside the time interval [60,80] and outside it.

$ 
W = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_x^2 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$

where $ Var(\epsilon_x) = \sigma_x^2 $

$ 
JGG = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$

$
X = (1-\phi) Indicator_t $ where $Indicator_t$ = 1 $\in$ [61,80] and 0 zero outside and Indicator_t has 100 rows and 1 column.

In words, I need JGG and X to implement the time varying nature of GG in the language of dlm.

JGG[1,6]=1 means that the (1,6) element of GG is time varying and to be found in the 1st column of X. I use it to tell the software that $\mu_1$ kicks in only in a certain time period $I_t / Indicator_t$.

$ 
FF = 
\begin{bmatrix} .25 && .25 && .25 && .25 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} 
$

$
V= \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_y^2 \end{bmatrix}
$

where $ Var(\epsilon_y) = \sigma_y^2 $

**Here is the code which implements this.**

```
library(dlm)
library(zoo)

# Set parameter restrictions
# parm[1] = Phi, the AR1 parameter of the x series.I have constrained this to be between -1 and 1.
# parm[2] = the error variance in the x series. I have constrained this to be positive.
# parm[3] = the error variance in the y series. I have constrained this to be positive.

parm_rest <- function(parm){
    return(
        c(1-2*exp(parm[1])/(1+exp(parm[1])),
          exp(parm[2]),
          exp(parm[3]))
    )
}

# We setup the state space model.

ssm1 <- function(parm,indicator_matrix){
    
    parm <- parm_rest(parm)
    
    r1 = c(parm[1],0,0,0,1-parm[1],0)
    r2 = c(1,rep(0,5))
    r3 = c(0,1,rep(0,4))
    r4 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0)
    r5 = c(rep(0,4),1,0)
    r6 = c(rep(0,5),1)
    GG1 = rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
    JGG = diag(rep(0,6))
    JGG[1,6] = 1
    W1 = diag(c(parm[2],0,0,0,0,0))
    return(
        dlm(
            FF = matrix(c(rep(.25,4),0,0),nr=1),
            V = parm[3],
            GG = GG1,
            JGG = JGG,
            W = W1,
            m0 = matrix(c(rep(0,4),0,0),nr=6),
            # I set the first 4 state variables = x[t]=...=x[t-3]= 0
            # the 5th/6th state variable = 0
            # C0 = diag(c(rep(solve(1-parm[1]^2)*parm[2],4),0))
            # parm[1] is between -1 and 1 and can be zero. That is why I did NOT do the above as it may lead to division by 0.
            C0 = diag(c(rep(100,6))),
            # There is some uncertainty in the x[0],...,x[3],mu and mu_0.
            X = (1-parm[1]) * indicator_matrix
            )
    )
}



set.seed(1234)
x <- as.zoo( 5 + arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.4)), n=103, sd=1.5))
# A jump of 25 in the time period 61+3 to 80+3. The 3 accounts for the 3 lags of x[t] in y[t], ie y[t] = (x[t] + x[t-1] +  x[t-2] + x[t-3])/4 + e_y[t]. When t=61 in y[t], t=64  in the original x[t]/mu[t] = 63 because we drop 3 observations in the start of x[t] to compute y[t].
x1 <- x + c(rep(0,63),rep(25,20),rep(0,20))    
y <- zoo::rollapply(x1, width=4, FUN=mean, align="right") + rnorm(100, sd=.1)

M = matrix(c(rep(0,60),rep(1,20),rep(0,20)),nr=100)

# estimate parameters
fit1 <- dlmMLE(y,parm=c(1,1,1),build=ssm1,indicator_matrix=M,hessian=T)

# get estimates

coef <- parm_rest(fit1$par)

# get standard errors using delta method
dg1 <- -2 * exp(fit1$par[1])/(1+exp(fit1$par[1]))^2
dg2 <- exp(fit1$par[2])
dg3 <- exp(fit1$par[3])
dg <- diag(c(dg1,dg2,dg3))
var <- dg%*%solve(fit1$hessian)%*%dg

# Compute parameters and their SE's.

coef;coef.se= sqrt(diag(var))

names(coef) <- c("Phi","e_x_variance","e_y_variance")
names(coef.se) <- c("Phi","e_x_variance","e_y_variance")

coef + 2 * coef.se
coef - 2 * coef.se
```

**Notice: I had set $\phi$=.4 and it is NOT covered in the computed confidence interval.**

```
> coef + 2 * coef.se
         Phi e_x_variance e_y_variance 
  0.20322352   4.35943466   0.01695791 
> 
> coef - 2 * coef.se
          Phi  e_x_variance  e_y_variance 
-0.0017584815  2.2680911327  0.0003373454 
>
```

**Attempt 2:**
**Outline: I make $\mu[t]=\mu[t-1]$ a state variable with zero variance, except at t=61 and t=81, where the variance  is allowed to be huge ( but equal at both t=61/81). This will make $\mu$ constant except that it will jump up at t=61 and jump down to the same level at t=81. Is this the right approach? Is there any other way of modelling this problem?**

This is inspired by: the example on Page 8 of [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf)

The state vector is :

$\theta[t+1]$ =

$
\begin{bmatrix}
x[t] \\ x[t-1] \\ x[t-2] \\ x[t-3] \\ \mu[t+1] \\ \mu[t]
\end{bmatrix}
$

The matrix $GG$ is then:

$ GG = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\phi && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && -\phi \\
1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$

$ W = 
\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_x[t] && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$

$ 
JW = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$

and

$ X = \sigma_{\mu}^2 * I_t$ where $I_t = 1$ for t $\in$ [61,81] and 0 otherwise. It is a matrix with 100 rows and 1 column.

Let
$
FF = \begin{bmatrix} .25 \\ .25 \\ .25 \\ .25 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

The measurement equation is :-

$ z[t+1] = FF  * \theta[t+1] = .25 * (x[t] + x[t-1] + x[t-2] + x[t-3]) + \epsilon_z[t+1]$

$ V =$ Variance in the measurement equation. = $Var(\epsilon_z) $

$z[t]$ seems to be  a lagged version of $y[t]$.  I am not sure.

$y[t] = .25 ( x[t] + x[t-1] + x[t-2] + x[t-3] ) + \epsilon_y[t]$.

Can I say :

Let $\epsilon_y[t] = \epsilon_z[t+1]$ and hence, $y[t] = z[t+1]$

Would that be correct?

**Here is a program that implements the above,it gives me an error,I do not know how to fix this.** Can someone please help me ?

```
library(dlm)
library(zoo)
# Set parameter restrictions
# parm[1] = Phi, the AR1 parameter of the x series.I have constrained this to be between -1 and 1.
# parm[2] = the error variance in the x series. I have constrained this to be positive.
# parm[3] = the error variance in the z series. I have constrained this to be positive.
# parm[4] = the variance of mu at t=61 and t=81.
parm_rest <- function(parm){
    return(
        c(1-2*exp(parm[1])/(1+exp(parm[1])),
          exp(parm[2]),
          exp(parm[3]),
          exp(parm[4]))
    )
}

# We setup the state space model.

ssm1 <- function(parm,indicator_matrix){
    
    parm <- parm_rest(parm)
    
    r1 = c(parm[1],0,0,0,1,-parm[1])
    r2 = c(1,rep(0,5))
    r3 = c(0,1,rep(0,4))
    r4 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0)
    r5 = c(rep(0,4),1,0)
    r6 = c(rep(0,4),1,0)
    GG1 = rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
    W1 = diag(c(parm[2],0,0,0,0,0))
    JW = diag(c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
    JW[5,5] = 1
    return(
        dlm(
            FF = matrix(c(rep(.25,4),0,0),nr=1),
            V = parm[3],
            GG = GG1,
            W = W1,
            m0 = matrix(rep(0,6),nr=6),
            # Set ALL state variables to the mean value of x[t] prior to the jump OR set it to zero with a lot of uncertainty.I chose the latter.
            # C0 = diag(c(rep(solve(1-parm[1]^2)*parm[2],4),0))
            # parm[1] is between -1 and 1 and can be zero. That is why I did NOT do the above as it may lead to division by 0.
            C0 = diag(c(rep(100,6))),  
            X = parm[4] * indicator_matrix
        )
    )    
}

set.seed(1234)
x <- as.zoo( 5 + arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.4)), n=103, sd=1.5))

# A jump of 25 in the time period 61+3 to 80+3. The 3 accounts for the 3 lags of x[t] in y[t], ie y[t] = (x[t] + x[t-1] +  x[t-2] + x[t-3])/4 + e_y[t]. When t=61 in y[t], t=64  in the original x[t]/mu[t] = 63 because we drop 3 observations in the start of x[t] to compute y[t].

x1 <- x + c(rep(0,63),rep(25,20),rep(0,20))    

y <- zoo::rollapply(x1, width=4, FUN=mean, align="right") + rnorm(100, sd=.1)


M = matrix(rep(0,100),nr=100)
M[c(61,81),1]<-1

    # estimate parameters
    fit1 <- dlmMLE(y,parm=c(1,1,1),build=ssm1,indicator_matrix= M,hessian=T)

    # get estimates
    print(fit1)

    coef <- parm_rest(fit1$par)

    # get standard errors using delta method
    dg1 <- -2 * exp(fit1$par[1])/(1+exp(fit1$par[1]))^2
    dg2 <- exp(fit1$par[2])
dg3 <- exp(fit1$par[3])
    dg <- diag(c(dg1,dg2,dg3))
    var <- dg%*%solve(fit1$hessian)%*%dg

    # Compute parameters and their SE's.

    coef;coef.se= sqrt(diag(var))

    names(coef) <- c("Phi","e_x_variance","e_z_variance","variance_mu_at_the_jump")
    names(coef.se) <- c("Phi","e_x_variance","e_z_variance","variance_mu_at_the_jump")
```

Here is where the code breaks:

````
>     # estimate parameters
>     fit1 <- dlmMLE(y,parm=c(1,1,1),build=ssm1,indicator_matrix= M,hessian=T)

Error in optim(parm, logLik, method = method, ...) : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [3]
```
````